# Change state of a child react

Tags: reactjs

That my code I don't know how to change the state, is I had in the onclickevent: "console.log("clicked" + index) it worked and then it did not work

```
import React from "react";

interface HeaderListProps {
  children: string;
  onClickEvent?: () => void;
  active: boolean; // Updated assignment
}

class HeaderList extends React.Component<HeaderListProps> {
  active: boolean;
  children: string;
  onClickEvent?: () => void;

  constructor(props: HeaderListProps) {
    super(props);
    this.active = false;
    this.children = props.children;
    this.onClickEvent = props.onClickEvent; // Updated assignment
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <li
        className={
          "p-1 rounded-xl cursor-pointer transition duration-200 hover:bg-red-300 hover:text-gray-900 hover:scale-105 hover:shadow-xl" +
          (this.active ? " bg-red-300" : "")
        }
        onClick={this.onClickEvent}
      >
        {this.children}
      </li>
    );
  }
}

export default HeaderList;
```

```
import HeaderList from "./headerList";
import { useState } from "react";

interface HeaderProps {
  pdp?: string;
  navItems: string[];
}

function Header({ pdp = "", navItems }: HeaderProps) {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(-1);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="inline-flex flex-row h-auto min-h-16 w-screen items-center bg-gray-800 shadow-lg">
        <img src="" alt="logo" className="mx-3 p-auto h-full" />
        <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold mx-3 h-full">AccessAutoMoto</h1>
        <ul className="list-none inline-flex flex-row flex-wrap gap-3 items-center justify-center m-3 nav-list">
          {navItems.map((item, index) => (
            <HeaderList
              key={index}
              onClickEvent={() => setActive(index)}
              active={active == index ? true : false}
            >
              {item}
            </HeaderList>
          ))}
        </ul>
        <i></i>
        <img src={pdp} alt="pdp" className="ml-auto mr-3 cursor-pointer" />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

I tried to make a nav bar that allows only one item to be activated (to see on which page we are).
I tried first to change the state in the headerList, but I was able to activate multiple of them and now I try that but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies in your class component, you're just not using the right variables.
Unless you really have to keep it as a class, I'd suggest to convert that to a FC.
If you need a class component then, you need to remove the constructor.

```js
import React from 'react';

type HeaderListProps = {
  active?: boolean;
  onClickEvent?: () => void;
}

const HeaderList = ({ active = false, children, onClickEvent }: PropsWithChildren<HeaderListProps>) => {
  return (
    <li
      className={
        "p-1 rounded-xl cursor-pointer transition duration-200 hover:bg-red-300 hover:text-gray-900 hover:scale-105 hover:shadow-xl" +
        (active ? " bg-red-300" : "")
      }
      onClick={onClickEvent}
    >
      {children}
    </li>
  );
}

export default HeaderList;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems here. First, you are using `key={index}` on the loop, which is not a good idea because React uses that to keep track of whether that element belongs to which component. [Reference](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#keeping-list-items-in-order-with-key). So you need to change the map in to something like this:

```
{navItems.map((item) => (
  <HeaderList
    key={item}
    onClickEvent={() => setActive(item)}
    active={item === active}
  >
    {item}
  </HeaderList>
))}
```

Then, you have a class component which is [not recommended anymore](https://react.dev/reference/react/Component) and you're not using the `active` prop. It should look something like this:

```
function HeaderList({ active, onClickEvent, children }: HeaderListProps) {
  return (
    <li
      className={
        "p-1 rounded-xl cursor-pointer transition duration-200 hover:bg-red-300 hover:text-gray-900 hover:scale-105 hover:shadow-xl" +
        (active ? " bg-red-300" : "")
      }
      onClick={onClickEvent}
    >
      {children}
    </li>
  );
}
```